# How to free a linked list with pointers

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I was trying to free memory for a linked list iteratively. The list has a struct which looks like this, and in this linked list, I don't add a url if it's in this list.

```
struct Node {
    char *url;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

Once done working with this linked list, I tried to free it, but got segmentation fault, I'm still in the way of learning `c`, I haven't got much clue of how to debugging such error other than directly searching for related topics. Referenced a few SOs [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113510/free-memory-from-linked-list-in-c), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417158/c-how-to-free-nodes-in-the-linked-list)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915369/how-to-free-a-struct-that-contains-only-pointers), still cannot figure out where it got crashed.

Here's my code. Free feel to add comments if you think anything I missed in this implementation.

```
void url_push(struct Node *head, const char *url, size_t url_size) {
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->url = malloc(url_size);
    new_node->next = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < url_size; i++)
        *(new_node->url + i) = *(url + i);

    struct Node *current = head;
    while(1) {
        if (strcmp(current->url, new_node->url) == 0) {
            printf("Seen page %s!!!!!\n", new_node->url);
            free(new_node);
            break;
        } else if (current->next == NULL) {

            current->next = new_node;
            break;
        } else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    head->url = "/";
    head->next = NULL;

    char *url = "www.google.com";
    url_push(head, url, strlen(url));

    url = "www.yahoo.com";
    url_push(head, url, strlen(url));

    url = "www.google.com";
    url_push(head, url, strlen(url));

    url = "www.wsj.com";
    url_push(head, url, strlen(url));

    struct Node *current = NULL;

    while ((current = head) != NULL) {
        printf("url: %s\n", head->url);

        head = head->next;
        free(current->url);
        free(current);
    }
}
```

**Edited:**
To reduce the confusions, I revised the struct. The purpose of using `strcmp` is to avoid adding a url that already seen.

Comment: You need a `remove()` method which implements the logic to remove a single node in the list. This must take care to reconnect the previous node to the next node in the list.

Comment: There is too much wrong to answer your question. How are the invalid, redirect, and page_size variables set? What is current pointer for if you never move it?  Head should never be moved since it is the start of the list. Why are you even freeing the list when you can just end the program?

Comment: Please provide [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You edited the struct, but now your code doesn't compile. If you provide code that isn't identical to what you're working with (which you usually should), make sure it reproduces the same problem.

Comment: [here](http://rextester.com/JUUBPH27071), take a look to a good implementation exemple ;) like linus say "don't talk show me the code"

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < url_size; i++)
        *(new_node->url + i) = *(url + i);` Now, what is this? An attemp t at strcpy()?

Comment: @wildplasser. Yeah, forget we have `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you do not allocate space for the null terminator for the `new_node->url` strings in `url_push`, causing `strcmp()` too have undefined behavior.
- the first node is not properly constructed: its `url` pointer is not allocated.
- you so not check for memory allocation failure

You should make `url_push()` more generic: it should handle empty lists by returning the new `head` pointer.  You do not need to pass the length of the `url` string, just use `strdup()`, and you should avoid allocating a new node before checking for duplicates.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
    char *url;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *url_push(struct Node *head, const char *url) {

    struct Node *current = head;
    if (current != NULL) {
        for (;;) {
            if (strcmp(current->url, url) == 0) {
                printf("Seen page %s before!!!!!\n", url);
                return head;
            } else if (current->next == NULL) {
                break;
            } else {
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
    struct Node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    if (new_node == NULL || (new_node->url = strdup(url)) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (current == NULL) {
        head = new_node;
    } else {
        current->next = new_node;
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    struct Node *head = NULL;

    head = url_push(head, "/");
    head = url_push(head, "www.google.com");
    head = url_push(head, "www.yahoo.com");
    head = url_push(head, "www.google.com");
    head = url_push(head, "www.wsj.com");

    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("url: %s\n", head->url);
        struct Node *current = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(current->url);
        free(current);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was just wondering does char *url = "www.google.com" has a terminating 0? If it has one, why cannot we use strcpy? If it doesn't have one, should we also add the 0 to url?

Comment: @GabrielChu: string literals of course have a null terminator. You can use `strcpy` if you allocate the proper size: `strlen(url) + 1`, but you can use the Posix normalized function `strdup()` that does both the allocation and the copy.

Answer (score 2):

`head->url = "/";`

That is not malloced data so you can't free it!

Your other problem is in `url_push()` with `new_node->url = malloc(url_size);` which does not allocate enough space for the terminating 0 in the string (nor does it copy the terminating 0 so you end up not "stomping on memory" but do have unterminated strings...). Try `new_node->url = strdup(url);` instead.

Style wise: calculate `url_size` in `url_push()` instead of making each caller call `strlen()` do it once inside the function being called (note if you use `strdup()` then you don't need the `url_size` at all.

Final note: A tool like valgrind would find both of these problems easily.